# All the Swing frames get "frozen" when wait() is called in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, mutex, monitor

I want to **wait()** the **put()** method called from the second thread which has been connected to the Server (Monitor). But when i do this, the whole GUI frames (Swing) including their elements get frozen aftr the second put() call. How to fix this? I want the second thread keep waiting till the first thread performs a get() which frees a slot. Thanks in advance. Here's my skeleton code:

Server:

```
Buffer<String> buf = new Buffer<String>(1);
while(true){
   //for each socket connected           
   new ServerHandler(..., buf).start();

}
```

ServerHandler:

```
public class ServerHandler extends Thread {

  Buffer<Messenger> buf;

  public void run(){
      buf.put("Test");
  }
}
```

Buffer:

```
public class BufferImp<String>
    private String[] requests;
    private int cur_req_in; // current Request in the queue
    private int req_size;
    private int req_count;

 public BufferImp(int size) {
        this.req_size = size;
        requests = new String[size];
        this.cur_req_in = 0;
        this.req_count = 0;
    }

 public synchronized void put(E o) throws InterruptedException {

        while(req_size == req_count) this.wait();

        requests[cur_req_in] = o;
        cur_req_in = (cur_req_in + 1) % req_size;
        req_count++;
        notifyAll();


    }
}
```

Comment: Who's calling `notify`/`notifyAll`? And how does your GUI interact with these threads?

Comment: are these `while(true)` loops just samples or the actual code?

Comment: @matt b: i have stripped off some parts. while(true) listens to incomming socket connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call wait when code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Instead you need to create a separate Thread for your long running task,

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: does this issue come only in Swing? The reference site im using has a similar Program (BoundedBuffer) and it uses AWT. http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/BoundedBuffer.html

Comment: I'm still skeptical about mapping my above code to SwingWorker methods.  what should go to doInBackground(), done()? thanks

Answer (score 4):

This happens if you wait() in the AWT-EventQueue thread. You should never wait there (no new events can be handled and gui frezes). Use a SwingWorker instead which waits for the response.

-> http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html