# Adding additional panels to a JFrame which lives in a EventDispath thread, from outside that?

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread, event-dispatching

I create a new frame in EventDispatch thread and want to add new Panels to that later on. But all i get is a blank frame, with 0 height. But panels added from inside the inner class are displayed. How to add using showFirstFrame()? 
I had to follow such an approach after getting this issue: [All the Swing frames get "frozen" when wait() is called in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680160/all-the-swing-frames-get-frozen-when-wait-is-called-in-java/7680205#7680205)

I've been referring to this tutorial: http://leepoint.net/JavaBasics/gui/gui-commentary/guicom-main-thread.html

Thanks in advance.

```
public class GUIController {
    JFrame bf;
    JFrame tempFrame;

    public JFrame showFrame(){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                            try {
                                Class c;
                                Constructor ctr;
                                c = Class.forName("SomeJFrame");
                                ctr = c.getConstructor();
                                GUIController.this.bf.removeAll();
                                GUIController.this.bf = (BaseFrame) ctr.newInstance();
                                GUIController.this.bf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                                GUIController.this.bf.pack();
                                GUIController.this.bf.setVisible(true);

                        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }

                }
            });

  return  GUIController.this.bf;
}


public void showFirstFrame(){
         tempFrame = showFrame();
        tempFrame .getContentPane().add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
           tempFrame .getContentPane().add(new EnterSomePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
           tempFrame .getContentPane().add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            tempFrame .setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
...

class GUIController {


    HeaderPanel headerPanel = new HeaderPanel(); // extends JPanel
    FooterPanel footerPanel = new FooterPanel();
    BaseFrame bf = new BaseFrame(); // extends JFrame

    public BaseFrame showFrame(String frameName){


         try {
                        Class c;
                        Constructor ctr;
                        c = Class.forName("some.dynamically.loaded.JFrame" + frameName);
                        ctr = c.getConstructor();
                        bf = (BaseFrame) ctr.newInstance();
                        bf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        bf.pack();
                        bf.setVisible(true);

                    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(GUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

        return bf;

    }


    public void showFirstFrame(final String frame){ //some controller will pass a frame name to this

        bf =  showFrame(frame);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    bf.getContentPane().add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                    bf.invalidate();
                    bf.validate();
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
         });


    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        GUIController c = new GUIController();
        c.showFirstFrame("FirstFrame");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod hi added the EDITED code. pls have a look. hope it will be clear now.

Comment: Sorry, your example is neither complete nor compilable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't recreate GUI this way, if you want ot only switch betweens two [JPanels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) inside [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) then you have two very simple choises

1) JFrame has by defalut [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), and if you put there `JPanel` (`add.myPanel;`) then this `JPanel` is placed to the `CENTER` area and occupated whole `JFrame`, and in `BorderLayout` only one `JComponent` could be placed to the concrete area, then you will call only (no remove, any reason for that)

```
myFatherPanel.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

2) and best of all would be lay your GUI by using [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), then you can pretty to forgot about all problems with your GUI

3) more safer would be to place (to the `JFrame`) FatherPanel (that never has been removed) and remove `JComponents` from this `FatherPanel`, because if you calling for `JFrame#removeAll()`, then you removed `RootPane`, and from your `JFrame` stays there only `Borders` same  as you decribed

Comment: this is not about that. My code perfectly works without using a Event Dispatch. This is about Event-dispatching.

Comment: +1 These are more reliable approaches. If you want to load panels dynamically, use `removeAll()`, `add()` and `validate()`. `SwingSet2` and [`benojt`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/benojt/) are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

What else? Also with:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { ... }
}
```